# How to Set Progressbar CSS Style width by reading value from XSLT Element?

Tags: xslt

i am working on XML File where the student has Rate Element and want to transform such rate element value and display it as Progress bar using width style during the XML transformation to HTML to give nice visibility for the student skills rate

the XML Snippet code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cv xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CV.xsd">
    <student>
<skills>
       <skill >Java</skill>
       <rate>95</rate>
    </skills>
</student>
```

XSLT Code

```
<p>
    <xsl:value-of select="skill" />
    </p>
    <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:95%"><xsl:value-of select="rate" /></div>
    </div>
```

Question: How can i pass <xsl:value-of select="rate" /> to Progress bar CSS Style width to be automatically geting the value from the rate element?

Answer (score 1):

Check this Code

```
<p>
<xsl:value-of select="skill" />
</p>
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar bg-success">
<xsl:attribute name="style">
<xsl:text>width:</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="skills/rate" /><xsl:text>% 
</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="skills/rate" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to thank you so much for your comment and your wonderful solution is working fine